# Ubuntu Server - Opam installation issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opam

I am installing Ubuntu 18.04
I have done this before, and never had this issue, the installation of OPAM has always gone smoothly, except this time.

I run the code to install OPAM.

```
sudo apt install opam
```

The installation does not give any errors, everything seems to go normally.

Then I run this.

```
opam init
```

and this is my output

```
Checking for available remotes: rsync and local, git, mercurial, darcs. Perfect!
[WARNING] Recommended dependencies -- most packages rely on these:
            - m4


=-=- Fetching repository information =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[default] synchronized from https://opam.ocaml.org
[ERROR] Base package base-threads of compiler system not found! Ignored.
[ERROR] Base package base-bigarray of compiler system not found! Ignored.
[ERROR] Base package base-unix of compiler system not found! Ignored.
[ERROR] Inconsistent set of base compiler packages: {} needed but not included
        / { base-bigarray, base-threads, base-unix } extra
[ERROR] Initialisation failed
OpamGlobals.Exit(66)
```

Once this errors out, I am stuck and can not go any further.
As I mentioned at the top, I have installed this version of the server many times in the past, and installed OPAM without an issue, until now.
This is through Virtualbox, so I deleted the installment and reinstalled it again, thinking that maybe there was a bad install. But, I get the same error.

I did some researching through Google, and cannot find this exact issue, but found similar ones with this OPAM build issue.

An update. Performing as suggested by AndreasKralj

```
opam init --comp $1.2.2
Checking for available remotes: rsync and local, git, mercurial, darcs. Perfect!
[WARNING] Recommended dependencies -- most packages rely on these:
            - m4   
=-=- Fetching repository information =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[default] synchronized from https://opam.ocaml.org
Cannot find /home/darkness/.opam/compilers/.2.2/.2.2/.2.2.comp: .2.2 is not a valid compiler name.
[ERROR] Initialisation failed
OpamGlobals.Exit(1)
```

Any idea's on this one, will be greatly appreciated.
Wayne

Comment: do you have ocaml installed? sudo apt-get install ocaml opam

Comment: Yes, make sure ocaml is installed. You can also try `opam init --comp $ver` if for some reason the ocaml installation by itself doesn't work, replacing $ver with the version of ocaml you want installed.

Comment: Hello,  AndreasKralj. Please look at the edited post. Thank you.

Comment: I also tried opam init --comp $"1.2.2" .... and it still gives the same error.

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't clear. Go ahead and remove the $ and the quotes and you should be able to get whatever version of ocaml you need. Example:

`opam init --comp 4.02.3`

I'll try installing 1.2.2 on my machine, I'll see if I get the same error or not.

Comment: that did it, Andreas. Please post this information as Answer, and I will accept it. Thank you once again.

Comment: Glad it helped, no worries :) I just tested it on a Docker image of Ubuntu and confirmed it worked as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue, you'll need to do `opam init --comp 1.2.2` to ensure ocaml is installed properly and set as the version you want.

Comment: Thank you once again. Now I just need to remember everything that I had done before, to hopefully get Icecast and Liquidsoap working on this joker. Thank you once again, Andreas... Wayne

Comment: Not a problem :) Good luck!